# Getting only date without time in TypeScript and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, timestamp

I have the following code in TypeScript

```
const EmployeeDetailsSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  employeeId: { type: String },
  advance: {
    lastAdvanceClosedOn: { type: String },
    pending: { type: String },
    nextVacation: { type: String },
    IquamaStatus: { type: String },
    allowedAdvance: { type: Number },
    duration: { type: String },
    requiredAdvance: { type: Number },
    adDate: { type: Date, default: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate()) }}
}
);
```

And in my database table **adDate** is appearing like below;

**adDate : 2020-03-12T00:00:00.000+00:00**

But I want the output as below;

**adDate : 12-03-2020**

How can I achieve this with out changing the 'type' to String

Comment: Be aware, with format `12-03-2020` you loose sorting or `$gt`, `$lt` capabilities.

Comment: A Date itself does not have any format. What you see is how **your client displays** it. If you wand a different format then set it in typescript.

Comment: I believe that the best way would be to save as `isoString` in this way: `new Date().toISOString()`, and then do the display treatment by the front-end, since MongoDB's storage mechanism (BSON) does not have a date type without hour. Complete dates only.

Answer (score 0):

use moment.js

```
moment(<your Date goes here>).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
```

Then pass the value

Comment: This changes the `Date` to a `String` - which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

you should keep your data source itself as `Date` and not modify it, thats right. BUT when you try to render it to web / cli whatever it needs to be parsed to string for any format that is not integer. mongodb stores `Date` as [integer](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/working-with-dates). the number represents milliseconds since EPOCH.

@vishnu-shenoys answer is severely outdated. momentjs is officially no longer maintained and [should not be used](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status).

use [date-fns's format](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format) function instead.

you can also use native javascript to get the day, month and year from the date via the `Date` js type.